# How does scikit-learn's KNN calculate the probability estimates?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, knn

How does the implementation of KNN algorithm in scikit learn calculate the probability estimates for the `predict_proba(X)` method?

Comment: It's open source, you could read the code -> https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/b3ea3ed6a/sklearn/neighbors/_classification.py#L223

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the following example is extracted from sklearn docs but modified a little bit so you can understand what are we doing in this case, for more details see:
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.neighbors.KNeighborsClassifier.html
Let's say we have 6 points that are either class 0 or class 1:

```
#import libraries
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsClassifier
# Data
X = [[5,5], [3,3],[4,4.5], [8,9.3], [8,9.1],[10,15]]
y = [0, 0,0, 1, 1,1]
#  Define the knn and fit the model
neigh = KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=4)
neigh.fit(X, y)
# Examples
# Print the probabilities 0 and 1 respecetively
print('Predict probabilities of 0 and 1 ',neigh.predict_proba([[4,4]]))
# Print the probabilities of 0 and 1 
print('Predict probabilities of 0 and 1 ',neigh.predict_proba([[10,12]]))
```

What you are basically doing is saying ok we have n_neighbors=4, so
the closest four points  to the point [4,4] are: 3 of class 0 and 1 of class
1 therefore you have 3/4 = 0.75 of being class 1 aand 1/4 =0.25 of being class two (this is the first print). Note that if you set n_neighbors=3  and fit the model you would get  that the three closest elementsx are class 0 for the point [4,4] and therefore the probabilities will be [1,0] (3/3 = 1 of being class 1 and 0/3 = 0 of being class 0)
One question that may arise is : How do they define that a point is close to another one? Well, in the documentation says that they are using minkowski distance by default with p = 2 and that's equivalent to calculating euclidian distance between [4,4] and each of the points in your training data (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minkowski_distance)

Comment: Thanks! I can't believe the principle is so simple. I though some probabilities estimate techniques.